# Add a checkout hidden field with a random unique string value in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hidden-field

In Woocommerce, I would like to add a hidden field to in checkout page, which attribute value will be a custom generated unique random string of character.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to do it… try the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_order_notes', 'additional_hidden_checkout_field' );
function additional_hidden_checkout_field() {
    // echo '<input type="hidden" name="custom_unique_key" value="'.md5( microtime() . rand() ).'">';
    echo '<input type="hidden" name="yudu_pw" value="'.rand(102548, 984675).'">';
}
```

You will get something like this generated html code (just before order notes field):

```
<div class="woocommerce-additional-fields">
    <input type="hidden" name="yudu_pw" value="837542">
```

Then you could be able to save that custom random string of characters value using:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'additional_hidden_checkout_field_save', 20, 2 );
function additional_hidden_checkout_field_save( $order, $data ) {
    if( ! isset($_POST['yudu_pw']) ) return;

    if( ! empty($_POST['yudu_pw']) ){
        $order->update_meta_data( 'yudu_pw', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['yudu_pw'] ) );
    }
}
```

So this custom random string of characters value will be saved as order meta data…

All code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot. I tried to play around a little bit bacuase I would need the string to be max. 10 characters long.

Comment: Also, I would like the generated characters to show up somewhere in the order details page in the backend. How is that done? Sorry, I know I am a total mess. Maybe just point me in the right direction :)

Comment: Thanks again @LouicTheAztec - I marked the answer as accepted. Last thing: maybe you could tell me how to amend to code so as to have the string of max. 10 characters?

Comment: @user1915410 In your code `if( ! empty($_POST['custom_unique_key']) ){`  has to be `if( ! empty($_POST['yudu']) ){`